# Set apache&nginx reverse proxy to show website from other user public_html

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, public-html

I've installed Centos Panel and apache2&nginx&varnish with reverse proxy. I can see that default website when i got to server ip X.X.X.X is from `/usr/local/apache/htdocs`. When I created a new user I see automatically created `vhosts` and `public_html` in user home directory. My question is how I can redirect all request to a new user.

I don't wanna use `/usr/local/apache/htdocs`. Can someone help me to set a new user e.g. **new_user** as a default one and show me `public_html` when I enter my server ip address in browser?

Comment: Can you provide nginx/apache config

Comment: /apache2 and nginx?  Both these are web servers so why both?  Detail your software topology, put some configurations in the question, ...